# How to select a boolean value showing if there are any rows compliant to a condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need a request to return 1 if there are any compliant (to a where clause) rows (and 0 if there are no rows compliant) instead of returning the rows themselves. How to write such a request in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
if EXISTS(select statement here)
  SELECT 1
ELSE
  SELECT 0
```

or

```
declare @retvalue int

if EXISTS(select statement here)
  SET @retvalue = 1
ELSE
  SET @retvalue = 0

return @retvalue
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Says there is a syntax error. The subquery seems to be ok (tested). I've even tried `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1) THEN SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0;` but get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax` anyway.

Comment: I've to use @fluff solution because this one just doesn't work whatever I try. It looks much better but I can't fix its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) FROM table WHERE condition = 1;
```

Comment: I believe this will be slower than using `EXISTS()` since it has to count all rows as opposed to being able to short circuit the evaluation after one row is found.